# Wordpress : ERROR: "Table Prefix" must not be empty

Tags: php, wordpress

im trying to do a clean install of Wordpress 4.5.2 but running into an error at the database stage. After filling in the correct database details and clicking Submit i get this error:

ERROR: "Table Prefix" must not be empty.

After doing some research some users have fixed the issue by increasing the  post_max_size and upload_max_filesize under the PHP settings. I have done this but still get the same error. The apache logs etc. are not pointing torwards any exact error, just giving the 500 error GET /wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.html?step=2 HTTP/1.0

Im running Plesk 12.5.30 on RHEL7.2.

I have done many Wordpress installs before and this is the first time i have come across this issue. I have wordpress installed on a few other domains on the same server and they are running just fine, although they were not installed on this server merely copied over recently so unsure if the same error would have occured had i clean installed them as well.

Lastly, i have already tried deleting the domain and database and creating them again just incase and still have the same issue.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: check your wp-config file and db file

Comment: Hey, this is a clean install so the wp-config does not yet exist, only the sample file. If you copy and modify the sample file to include the correct DB details it allows you to move on to the next setup stage however at this point you then get the error "Admin is not a valid username" so still cannot install. Im assuming both error relate to the same issue, assuming server configuration. Thanks, Chris.

Comment: I do agree @Chris. As this thread is closed, I'm commenting to share that in my case it was a MySQL issue. Make sure that mysql extension is correctly enabled in your PHP installation (mysqli in php.ini file)

Answer (score -1):

You need to define [table prefix](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#table_prefix) in your `wp-config.php` file.

Example:

```
$table_prefix = 'chris_';
```

Comment: Hey, this is a clean install so the wp-config does not yet exist, only the sample file. If you copy and modify the sample file to include the correct DB details it allows you to move on to the next setup stage however at this point you then get the error "Admin is not a valid username" so still cannot install. Im assuming both error relate to the same issue, assuming server configuration. Thanks, Chris.

Answer (score -2):

In the folder where you install WordPress, there can't be any files. Maybe you have some other files there. Remove all files and try installing WordPress again.

Comment: The OP mentions that he deleted the domain and database, which on a Plesk server means the entire folder structure /var/www/vhosts/sitename is deleted. I think "remove the files and reinstall" is a bit too generic to be a helpful answer in this case. Perhaps you can elaborate on what specific config or files the OP should focus and investigate further?