# Wordpress: ERROR: "Table Prefix" must not be empty

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, amazon-aurora

So I'm trying to build a Wordpress website using AWS using RDS Aurora. I've installed the source code provided by wordpress.org and it uploaded successfully but after putting in all the information regarding the database it loads for a minute or two then says the page isn't working, when it reloads it gives me the error ERROR: "Table Prefix" must not be empty. I've tried many solutions but none of them are working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress : ERROR: "Table Prefix" must not be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831906/wordpress-error-table-prefix-must-not-be-empty)

Answer (score 1):

Check the URL of the installation page. It must have a `.php` suffix. If it doesn't, it's likely your `.htaccess` page is rewriting the URL and causing your POST requests to misdirect.

Edit `.htaccess` so it reads `RewriteEngine Off`.

This bug is often the result of inheriting `.htaccess` rules from higher directories.

Answer (score 0):

In a fresh installation rename your `wp-config-sample.php` file with `wp-config.php`.

Then define you own [table_prefix](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#table_prefix). Make it meaningfull related to your project. This table_prefix will be added as a the prefix of you tables in your database.

Example: `$table_prefix = abcd_`